# I am trying to send current time in database, all the data shown but time didn't show in orignal format like (h:m:s)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime

**My Model**
i can also add date helper,by this way time store like '1247443'

```
public function upload_msg()
{

    $data=array( 
           'user'      =>$this->input->post('name'),
           'message'     => $this->input->post('msg')
           );
           $this->db->set('time', 'NOW()', FALSE); 
           $insert=$this->db->insert('data',$data);
          return $insert;
}
```

Comment: welcome to stack. people are down voting you because they don't understand your question. show us more of what you have tried, the results, what you expected, etc.

Comment: what you want ? your want to insert the data in database? explain it in detail

Answer (score 0):

Use `date()` Function.

```
public function upload_msg()
{
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/City"); //date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Colombo")
    $data=array( 
           'user'      =>$this->input->post('name'),
           'message'     => $this->input->post('msg'),
           'your_table_field'     => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
           );
    $insert = $this->db->insert('data',$data);
    return $insert;
}
```